# SQL Query doesn't update database in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm new to php and MySQL and I'm currently trying to build a small website as a practice. I have this small error where I want to edit the payment in my database, the code runs and it says it's successful but it doesn't update in the table. I tried using a lot of different ways like creating views in my database but it still didn't work. The php page is supposed to get the user_id from the previous page and this works well, but it still doesn't update the table.

Here is the sql for my basket table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `basket` (


`product_id` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` mediumint(8) NOT NULL,
  `size` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `payment` varchar(6) NOT NULL default 'No',
  `checkout` varchar(3) NOT NULL default 'No'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `basket`
--

INSERT INTO `basket` (`product_id`, `user_id`, `quantity`, `size`, `payment`, `checkout`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 'Small', 'No', 'Yes'),
(3, 1, 1, 'Small', 'No', 'Yes'),
(20, 1, 1, 'Small', 'No', 'Yes'),
(3, 2, 1, 'Small', 'Yes', 'Yes');
```

Below is my php code as I'm using the view called payment_details in my database:

```
<?php
require_once('my_connect.php');
require_once 'header.php';
$user_id=$_GET["user_id"];?>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<H1>Edit Payment Form</H1>
<table>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['change_payment'])): 
        $user_id=$_GET["user_id"];
        $payment=$_POST["payment"];

        $edit_query= "update basket set 
                        payment = '$payment' where 
                        user_id='$user_id'"; 

        $edit_result= mysqli_query($connection, $edit_query);

        if ($edit_result) :
                header ('location: view_orders.php?confirm=Product item successfully updated');
        else :
                echo "<b>This didn`t work, error: </b>";
                echo mysqli_error($connection);
        endif;
    endif;


    $user_id=$_GET['user_id']; 
    $my_query="select * from basket where user_id=$user_id;"; 
    $result= mysqli_query($connection, $my_query);

    while ($myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):
        $user_id= $myrow['user_id'];
        $payment = $myrow["payment"];
    endwhile;

    echo "<form method='POST' action='change_payment.php' >
        <tr><td><b>Payment:</b>
        <td><input type='text' name='payment' value='$payment'> 
        <tr><td><input type='submit' name='change_payment' value='Save Changes'>
        </form>";
?>

</table>
</body>
</html>
</div>
<?php require_once('footer.php'); ?>
```

It doesn't update the basket table in my database and I wanna know why? Please help my with this and I'll be thankful.

Comment: is there any sql errors printed out ?

Comment: No errors at all, it takes me to the previous page as asked and adds the 'Product item successfully updated' but it's not updated.

Comment: print `$edit_query` and execute it manually from phpmyadmin and check out what's wrong

Comment: I tried that and it worked perfectly. The SQL code works but for an odd reason it doesn't update the table

Comment: then update your question with the `require_once('my_connect.php');` contents

Comment: Someone else suggested to try a code and this is what I got Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in C:\WebServ\wwwroot\htdocs\php\my-shop\footer.php on line 2 have any idea what it is?

Comment: The error is also is the user_id because when I delete it the database gets updated.

Comment: First make when u click submit button to check if $_GET['user_id']; is not empty and that is integer, if not empty get value from $_GET variable into your $user_id = (int)$_GET['user_id']; and then run rest of a script.

Comment: I edited my code, check it now it should work without any error.

Answer (score 1):

Since i can't comment (lack of reputation i have to write this as answer). First and foremost every mysql/i_query() should be beaten with a stick until it becomes prepared statement. As i can see you are handling payments and you are SQLInjection vulnerable. So first suggestion is read about SQLInjection and prepared statements. About question, try setting error reporting at the top of the script to:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

and write what happens after. Also dump $user_id before update query and check if there are some problems, as query will successfully update even if $user_id does not exist in database, it will update nothing but query is successfull.

Comment: I still didn't reach the payment page, this is a page for the admins only to update the database and I'm only trying that for practice, it isn't a real website. The error is as the following: Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in C:\WebServ\wwwroot\htdocs\php\my-shop\footer.php on line 2

Answer (score 0):

If MySQL has a similar syntax to MS SQL then the only issue I can see is the apostrophes around the table name and column names in your insert statement. You should only need apostrophes for the string values you are inserting.

Comment: These are backticks `\`` - It's the correct way to quote identifiers in MySQL.

Comment: Not sure if they're the same or not, I tried taking them down but it shows an error. I suppose that varchar is the same as string since I can insert numbers or words in a varchar(?)

Comment: Apologies for the red herring!

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works for me, and u have error here

```
"select * from basket where user_id=$user_id;"
```

this ; is error. And make sure u have user_id in your domain index.php?user_id=1

**EDIT** code updated with a checking if user_id exists in a URL if not it will not display form or update a script, because ur form reading input from database based on user_id.

```
<?php

require_once 'my_connect.php';
require_once 'header.php';

?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
<body>

<H1>Edit Payment Form</H1>
<table>

<?php

// if submit button is pressed
if (isset($_POST['change_payment']))
{

        // check if user_id is exists in a URL
        if (isset($_GET['user_id']) && !empty($_GET['user_id'])) 
        {
            // now if user_id exists and is not empty make a variable and run a rest of a script
            $user_id = (int)$_GET['user_id'];

            // get name from a form input field payment
            $payment = $_POST["payment"];

            // update basket table with payment where user_id is equal to user_id from a $_GET variable
            $edit_query = "UPDATE basket SET payment = '$payment' WHERE user_id = '$user_id'"; 

            // run query
            $edit_result = mysqli_query($connection, $edit_query);

            // if query is valid redirect user to another location
            if ($edit_result)
            {
                header('location: view_orders.php?confirm=Product item successfully updated');
            }
            else
            {
                // if query fails display error message
                echo "<b>This didn't work, error: </b>" . mysqli_error($connection);
            }
        }

}

// check if user_id is exists in a URL if not dont display a form
if (isset($_GET['user_id']) && !empty($_GET['user_id']))
{
    // now if user_id exists and is not empty make a variable and run a rest of a script
    $user_id = (int)$_GET['user_id'];

    // select all data from basket table where user_id is equal to user_id from a $_GET variable
    $my_query = "SELECT * FROM basket WHERE user_id = '$user_id'";

    // run query
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $my_query);

    // get an array with all data from basket table where user_id is equal to user_id from $_GET variable
    $myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    // show a form and set value to $myrow['payment'] where payment is equal to payment data where user_id is equal to user_id from a $_GET variable
    echo '
        <form method="POST" action="">
            <b>Payment:</b>
            <input type="text" name="payment" maxlength="6" value="'.$myrow['payment'].'"> 
            <input type="submit" name="change_payment" value="Save Changes">
        </form>
    ';
}

?>

</table>
</body>
</html>
</div>
<?php require_once 'footer.php'; ?>
```

And my_connect.php

```
<?php

// display errors, comment this 2 functions after make this script to work
error_reporting(1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

// starting session
session_start();

// connection to database
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');     // database host
define('DB_USER', 'root');          // database username
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');          // database pasword
define('DB_NAME', 'baza');          // database name

$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

?>
```

Comment: Can I know what is config.php?

Comment: ah sorry its my connection to database like yours my_connect.php just change it

Comment: No, it's okay. I tried putting your code, changed it to my_connect but it shows me error because of the '.$myrow['payment'].'" in the form

Comment: try to use before form var_dump($myrow); and u need to get an array. if u don't get anything check your connection to database. $connection = mysqli_connect('host', 'username', 'password', 'database name'); And make sure your $user_id=$_GET['user_id']; is not empty or exists in database 1 or 2.

Comment: I've tried everything, still getting an error. The only thing that's not letting the amount pass to the database is the user_id. When I delete it, the database is being updated (of course for everything) but when I put it back nothing happens.

Comment: try to remove this $user_id=$_GET['user_id']; and set $user_id=1; and u will need to get updated user with that id. if it change then its problem in your $_GET variable. and post code in header.php and footer.php maybe u have some error there.

Answer (score 0):

You must consider if it doesn't display error this don't mean the update  is done or not. It means the query is good (no syntax mistake).
So we can imagine you're trying to update the record of a user who don't exist. 
Eg: user_id = 10 and you try to update the record with user_id = 11. Syntax is OK, SQL will find no user with user_id = 11 but will replied "OK, I tried, syntax is OK so for me, it's nice".

What you must consider is checking the number of updated records (using eg $result = @mysqli_affected_rows($handle);) But also, you must understand that, even if the query is good, if the update don't change the value (so in your case if the old and new value of "payment" are the same), mysqli_affected_rows will returned 0.

What I suggest is just add a "echo" of your query before the call. Then copy- past this string into PhpMyadmin to see what's happening. Maybe while displaying the string of the query you'll see some values are wrong.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, everyone, for the help. I want to inform you that I managed to know where my mistake was. It was simply because the payment was in the basket table with a repeated user id, that's why it didn't manage to work. I moved it to the users table and it works well right now.